# Flutter, in nested scrollview (consisting of header and tabview ) the scrolling should not happen if the tabview has less or no data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a header widget and then a tab view. I have been able to make them scroll as one using a nestedscrollview. But I want the scrolling to not happen if tab view data is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Disable scroll if total child length < scroll height:

```
NestedScrollView(
       physics: (sumHeight>scrollHeight) ? AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
     )
```

Comment: Do I need to calculate the individual items height + tab bar height and then set it as sumHeight. Is there any better way?